# Most terse way to find a string value in an object of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, ecmascript-6, constants

So I have a bunch of status codes, in an object (from an API) that returns like this:

```
{
  "location": [
    "HOME_ADDRESS_INCOMPLETE",
    "HOME_MISSING_ADDRESS"
  ],
  "basics": [
    "HOME_MISSING_TYPE"
  ],
  "description": [
    "HOME_MISSING_DESCRIPTION"
  ],
  "immersions": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_STAY_REQUIRED",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_INTERESTED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_HOURLY_PRICE",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_WEEKLY_PACKAGES"
  ],
  "rooms": [
    "NO_ROOMS"
  ],
  "photos": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_HOME_IMAGE_REQUIRED"
  ],
  "pricing": [
    "MISSING_CURRENCY",
    "SERVICE_WITHOUT_PRICE",
    "DISCOUNT_WITHOUT_PERCENT",
    "ROOM_WITHOUT_PRICE"
  ]
}
```

The key names, like `location` correlate to a step in a setup wizard that the user must be placed on depending on what is missing, which is represented by constants like `HOME_ADDRESS_INCOMPLETE`.

What is the most terse or clear way to start with this object and one constant, like `MISSING_CURRENCY`, and return the name of the key to which that constant's array belongs to?

Here's what I have so far, but all it does is return the array itself:

```
const activeStep = Object.values(HomeStatusCodes).filter(statusArray => {
  return statusArray.includes(homeActivationResponse.code)
})
```

Comment: @Soviut Updated question

Comment: So in your example, searching for `MISSING_CURRENCY` should return `"pricing"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) (on the array of keys of that structure, from `Object.keys`) plus `Array#indexOf` should do it:

```
function find(value) {
  return Object.keys(data).find(function(key) {
    return data[key].indexOf(value) != -1;
  });
}
```

Note that `Array#find` is new in ES2015, but can readily be shimmed/polyfilled.

Example:

```js
var data = {
  "location": [
    "HOME_ADDRESS_INCOMPLETE",
    "HOME_MISSING_ADDRESS"
  ],
  "basics": [
    "HOME_MISSING_TYPE"
  ],
  "description": [
    "HOME_MISSING_DESCRIPTION"
  ],
  "immersions": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_STAY_REQUIRED",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_INTERESTED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_HOURLY_PRICE",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_WEEKLY_PACKAGES"
  ],
  "rooms": [
    "NO_ROOMS"
  ],
  "photos": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_HOME_IMAGE_REQUIRED"
  ],
  "pricing": [
    "MISSING_CURRENCY",
    "SERVICE_WITHOUT_PRICE",
    "DISCOUNT_WITHOUT_PERCENT",
    "ROOM_WITHOUT_PRICE"
  ]
};

function find(value) {
  return Object.keys(data).find(function(key) {
    return data[key].indexOf(value) != -1;
  });
}

console.log(find("MISSING_CURRENCY"));
```

Even more terse when you use ES2015 syntax:

```
const find = value =>
  Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key].indexOf(value) != -1);
```

(Yes, that's really a function.) Here's a live version of that for browsers that support ES2015:

```js
var data = {
  "location": [
    "HOME_ADDRESS_INCOMPLETE",
    "HOME_MISSING_ADDRESS"
  ],
  "basics": [
    "HOME_MISSING_TYPE"
  ],
  "description": [
    "HOME_MISSING_DESCRIPTION"
  ],
  "immersions": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_STAY_REQUIRED",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_HOURS",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_INTERESTED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_HOURLY_PRICE",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES",
    "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_WEEKLY_PACKAGES"
  ],
  "rooms": [
    "NO_ROOMS"
  ],
  "photos": [
    "AT_LEAST_ONE_HOME_IMAGE_REQUIRED"
  ],
  "pricing": [
    "MISSING_CURRENCY",
    "SERVICE_WITHOUT_PRICE",
    "DISCOUNT_WITHOUT_PERCENT",
    "ROOM_WITHOUT_PRICE"
  ]
};

const find = value =>
  Object.keys(data).find(key => data[key].indexOf(value) != -1);

console.log(find("MISSING_CURRENCY"));
```

Comment: @Drix: Quite. :-) That's what I get with starting with ES5 and then converting part of it to ES2015...

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the keys and find the one which property includes the wanted item.

```js
function getKey(object, item) {
    return Object.keys(object).find(k => object[k].includes(item));
}

var data = { "location": ["HOME_ADDRESS_INCOMPLETE", "HOME_MISSING_ADDRESS"], "basics": ["HOME_MISSING_TYPE"], "description": ["HOME_MISSING_DESCRIPTION"], "immersions": ["AT_LEAST_ONE_STAY_REQUIRED", "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_HOURS", "SIMPLE_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES", "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_HOURS", "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES", "TANDEM_STAY_MISSING_INTERESTED_LANGUAGES", "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_HOURLY_PRICE", "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_OFFERED_LANGUAGES", "TEACHER_STAY_MISSING_WEEKLY_PACKAGES"], "rooms": ["NO_ROOMS"], "photos": ["AT_LEAST_ONE_HOME_IMAGE_REQUIRED"], "pricing": ["MISSING_CURRENCY", "SERVICE_WITHOUT_PRICE", "DISCOUNT_WITHOUT_PERCENT", "ROOM_WITHOUT_PRICE"] };

console.log(getKey(data, 'MISSING_CURRENCY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a lookup map:

```
const stepByStatusCode = new Map()
for (const step in HomeStatusCodes) {
    for (const code of HomeStatusCodes[step])
        stepByStatusCode.set(code, step);
```

which you then can use in the most terse way

```
const activeStep = stepByStatusCode.get(homeActivationResponse.code);
```